# If $f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(\frac{a+b}{2})$ prove that any such function is a polynomial of degree $2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

Consider $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ to be differentiable function. $f(b)-f(a)=(b-a)f'(\frac{a+b}{2})$ for all $a,b \in \Bbb R$ prove that any such function is a polynomial of degree $2$.

I am trying using Taylor's expansion that any point $a$ we have

$$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+(x-a)^2/2f''(a)+\cdots$$.

then I observed that the function is not infinitely differentiable. So we can't use the Taylor Series. So, I don't think that proving that the higher order differentiation vanishes also won't help. We can use Lagrange mean value theorem, but how to proceed? Any hint!!

Comment: Is it given initially that the function is a polynomial?

Comment: The function IS infinitely differentiable because of the equation - since $f$ is differentiable, LHS of the equation
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} = f'\left( \frac{x+a}{2}\right)
$$
is differentiable for $x\neq a$, so for RHS. Varying $a$ shows that $f''(x)$ exists for all $x$.

Comment: The condition is also satisfied by constant functions and linear functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to state $f$ is differentiable.

Prove that $f$ is infinitely differentiable (hint: use $f'(x)=\dfrac{f(x+y)-f(x-y)}{2y}$).  Differentiating twice with respect to $y$, the equation
$$
f(x+y)-f(x-y)=2yf'(x)\quad\forall x,y
$$
gives
$$
f''(x-y)=f''(x+y)\quad\forall x,y.
$$
Hence $f''$ is a constant, so $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$.

Comment: Did the question states that $f''$ exists?

Comment: Write $f'(x)$ in two different ways: $f'(x)=\frac{f(2x)-f(0)}{2x}$ and $f'(x)=\frac{f(2x-1)-f(1)}{2x-2}$. The first one suggests $f'(x)$ is differentiable if $x\neq0$, and the second says the same for $x\neq1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're right, I forgot to mention that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: And logically if $f''$ is constant then $f''$ must be a polynomial, right?

Comment: Does there exists any $f$ which is non-polynomial function?