# If $\frac{1}{2y} \int_{x-y}^{x+y} f(t) \space \mathrm{d}t = f(x)$, then $f$ is linear

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

The problem is:

> $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a twice differentiable function such that
> $$ \frac{1}{2y} \int_{x-y}^{x+y} f(t) \space \mathrm{d}t = f(x) \quad [x \in \mathbb{R}, \space y>0] $$
> Show $f(x) = ax + b$ for some $a, b$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I have seen various solutions to this problem online, but I found one that does not use the twice-differentiable property, and was wondering if I had made a slip somewhere.

*Solution*

By differentiating w.r.t. $y$, we get

$$\frac{f(x+y) + f(x-y)}{2} = f(x)$$

This means that $f$ has the property that if any two points lie on the graph of $f$, so does their midpoint. As a corollary, if $P_1, P_2$ lie on this graph, then if $P_3$ is a point such that the midpoint of $P_1P_3$ is $P_2$, then $P_3$ lies on the the graph also.

So now let $A = (0, f(0)), \space B = (1, f(1))$, and the line joining them be given by $y = g(x) = ax+b$. By the property described above, this means that $f(\pm 2^n) = g(\pm 2^n) \space [n \in \mathbb{Z}]$. So by a 'binary search' procedure, we can, for any $k$, construct a sequence $a_n$ with $\lim a_n = k$ and $f(a_n) = g(a_n)$.

But then, since $f$ and $g$ are both continuous, we wind up with $f(k) = g(k)$, which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Well, this one is the equality case of a famous inequality from Putnam and Beyond. All the conditions remain the same and the equality is replaced by $\leqslant$, then $f$ is **convex**, and if replaced by $\geqslant$ then **concave**. Let's see the problem:
$$ f ( x ) \leq \frac{1}{2y} \int_{ x - y }^{ x + y } f ( t ) dt  \quad  \text{for all } x \in \mathbb{R}, y > 0$$Prove that

$ ( a ) $ the maximum of $ f $ on any closed interval is assumed at one of the endpoints, and

$ ( b ) $ the function is convex.

Comment: @binform You may like my other solutio. I have deleted the first solution now.

Answer (score 7):

Your approach is correct, but I think that you should give a full explanation of your statement:

> By the property described above, this means that $f(\pm 2^n) = g(\pm 2^n) \space [n \in \mathbb{Z}]$.

A shorter way. Starting from
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-y}^{x+y} f(t) \,dt = f(x)y$$
by differentiating with respect to $y$ we obtain
$$\frac{f(x+y) + f(x-y)}{2} = f(x)$$
This is your first step. Note that such identity holds for any $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now, we differentiate two more times with respect to $y$ (recall that $f$ is twice differentiable):
$$\frac{f'(x+y) - f'(x-y)}{2} = 0,$$
$$\frac{f''(x+y) + f''(x-y)}{2} = 0.$$
Finally, by letting $y=0$, we have that $f''(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and therefore $f(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3):

This is an interesting problem (albeit not too difficult) which admits a solution under a considerably more general hypothesis, as follows:

> Assume $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is *continuous* and that the relation:
> $$\frac{1}{2y}\int_{x-y}^{x+y}f(t)\mathrm{d}t=f(x)$$
> holds for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $y>0$. Then $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$-**affine** (this means it is a an affine endomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ regarded as an affine space over itself with the canonical structure or in more simple terms that there exist coefficients $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$; if we are to be pedantic with the algebraic nuances, "affine" is the correct term to be used here, "linear" bearing a slightly different - albeit related - meaning).

*Proof.* Since $f$ is continuous it is automatically Riemann integrable on every compact interval and furthermore the function:
$$\begin{align*}
F \colon \mathbb{R} &\to \mathbb{R}\\
F(x):&=\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}$$
is a *primitive* of $f$ (by virtue of the *Fundamental Theorem of Calculus*). The hypothesis relation can be rewritten as $F(x+y)-F(x-y)=2yf(x)$ and bearing in mind the differentiability of $F$ entails indeed:
$$f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x) \tag{*}$$
for any $x \in \mathrm{R}$ and $y>0$, by differentiation with respect to $y$, as you and many other users have pointed out above.

Notice that the above relation is equivalently expressed as:
$$f\left(\frac{u+v}{2}\right)=\frac{f(u)+f(v)}{2} \tag{**}$$
for any real numbers $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$. Indeed, this claim is trivially valid for $u=v$ and in the case $u \neq v$ we can assume without any loss of generality that $u<v$. By setting $x:=\frac{v+u}{2}$ and $y:=\frac{v-u}{2}$ we have $y>0$ and the relation $(^*)$ applied to this particular choice of $x$ and $y$ leads immediately to $(^{**})$.

In order to show that $f$ is affine it suffices to prove that for any $t, x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ one has the relation $f(tx+(1-t)y)=tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ (this relation is actually characteristic to affine maps). Indeed, were such a relation to take place we would have:
$$f(x)=f(x1+(1-x)0)=xf(1)+(1-x)f(0)=(f(1)-f(0))x+f(0)$$
valid for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, rendering $f$ into the desired form. We shall thus consider the set:
$$T:=\{t \in \mathbb{R}|\ (\forall x, y)(x, y \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow f(tx+(1-t)y)=tf(x)+(1-t)f(y))\}$$
and make it our subsequent objective to prove that $T=\mathbb{R}$.

We begin by remarking that by definition the set $T$ is stable with respect to the map $t \mapsto 1-t$, in other words that $1-T \subseteq T$ (and since this map is clearly an involution we can furthermore assert that $1-T=T$). It is also immediate that $\{0, 1\} \subseteq T$ and by virtue of relation $(^{**})$ we also gather that $\frac{1}{2} \in T$. Let us now establish in order a number of properties of the set $T$ which will eventually lead us to our desired conclusion:

1. The relation $\frac{1}{2}(T+T) \subseteq T$ holds, in other words for any $s, t \in T$ their arithmetic mean $\frac{1}{2}(s+t) \in T$ is also in $T$. Considering arbitrary $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have the relations:
   $$\begin{align*}
   f\left(\frac{s+t}{2}x+\left(1-\frac{s+t}{2}\right)y\right)&=f\left(\frac{sx+(1-s)y}{2}+\frac{tx+(1-t)y}{2}\right)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}f(sx+(1-s)y)+\frac{1}{2}f(tx+(1-t)y)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}(sf(x)+(1-s)f(y))+\frac{1}{2}(tf(x)+(1-t)f(y))\\
   &=\frac{s+t}{2}f(x)+\left(1-\frac{s+t}{2}\right)f(y),
   \end{align*}$$
   which prove our assertion.
2. $T$ is a *closed* subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (with respect to the standard topology, of course). Indeed, consider a fixed pair of elements $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and define the map:
   $$\begin{align*}
   h_{x, y} \colon \mathbb{R} &\to \mathbb{R}\\
   h_{x, y}(t)\colon&=f(tx+(1-t)y)-tf(x)+(t-1)f(y).
   \end{align*}$$
   On account of $f$ being continuous, $h_{x, y}$ will also be continuos for every double index $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and therefore the zero set $h_{x, y}^{-1}[\{0\}]$ will be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Since by definition:
   $$T=\bigcap_{x, y \in \mathbb{R}}h_{x, y}^{-1}[\{0\}]$$
   and arbitrary intersections of closed subsets are closed, we conclude that $T$ is closed.
3. For arbitrary subsets $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $N \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{\times}$ write $\frac{M}{N}\colon=\left\{\frac{x}{y}\right\}_{\substack{x \in M \\ y \in N}}$. For any $u \in \mathbb{R}$ similarly write $u^{\mathbb{N}}\colon=\{u^n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Here we make the claim that:
   $$\frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}} \cap [0, 1] \subseteq T.$$
   Indeed, on the grounds of observation 1) above it is easy to prove by induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $\frac{1}{2^n}\mathbb{N}\cap [0, 1] \subseteq T$. The base case $n=0$ amounts to the claim $\mathbb{N} \cap [0, 1]=\{0, 1\} \subseteq T$ which we have already remarked is true. Assuming the claim for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let us prove it for $n+1$. To this end, let $m \in \mathbb{N}$ be such that $\frac{m}{2^{n+1}} \in [0, 1]$ or in other words $0 \leqslant m \leqslant 2^{n+1}$. If $m \leqslant 2^n$ it is clear that $\frac{m}{2^n} \in \frac{1}{2^n}\mathbb{N} \cap [0, 1]$ and owing to the induction hypothesis we gather $\frac{m}{2^n} \in T$. Hence, from 1) we infer that $\frac{m}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{0+\frac{m}{2^n}}{2} \in T$. If on the other hand $2^n<m\leqslant 2^{n+1}$ we derive $0<m-2^n \leqslant 2^n$ and subsequently $\frac{m-2^n}{2^n}=\frac{m}{2^n}-1 \in T$ thanks to the induction hypothesis. Applying observation 1) once again we can infer that $\frac{1+\left(\frac{m}{2^n}-1\right)}{2}=\frac{m}{2^{n+1}} \in T$, since $1 \in T$.

---

**For reasons of a lagging compiler when the input text excedes a certain length limit, I will ask the interested reader to bear with me throughout the next posting, where I will continue this current proof.**

Comment: (+1) Nice detailed proof of a more general result.

Comment: @Robert Z Thank you for your comment! I am not yet done with it, so please bear with me to the end if you wish to see it fully delivered.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{2y} \int_{x-y}^{x+y} f(t) dt=f(x). $$
D. w.r. t. $y$ using Lebnitz
$$-\frac{1}{2y^2}\int_{x-y}^{x+y} f(t) dt +\frac{1}{2y} [f(x+y)-(-1)f(x-y)]=0$$
Use (1) again to get
$$\implies f(x)=\frac{1}{2}[f(x+y)+f(x-y)].$$
This will be satisfied only by $f(x)=mx+c.$

Answer (score 1):

**Continuation of the above**

4. From 2) and 3) above we derive the fact that:
   $$T \supseteq \overline{\frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}}\cap [0, 1]}=[0, 1].$$
   Let us give a justification for the equality in the relation stated above. On the one hand, since $\frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}}\cap [0, 1] \subseteq [0, 1]$ and $[0, 1]$ is closed we have the obvious inclusion $\overline{\frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}}\cap [0, 1]} \subseteq [0, 1]$. Conversely, let us consider arbitrary $x \in (0, 1)$ together with arbitrary $t \in \left(0, \min\{x, 1-x\}\right)$, which means that $(x-t, x+t) \subset (0, 1)$. By reasons of archimedeanity, since $t>0$ there exists $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^{m+1}t>1$. This means that the interval $(2^m(x-t), 2^m(x+t))$ has length greater than $1$ and therefore $(2^m(x-t), 2^m(x+t)) \cap \mathbb{Z} \neq \varnothing$. We can therefore fix a certain $r \in (2^m(x-t), 2^m(x+t)) \cap \mathbb{Z}$, which leads to the inequalities $x-t<\frac{r}{2^m}<x+t$. Since $x-t>0$ we gather that $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and hence that $\frac{r}{2^m} \in (x-t, x+t) \cap \frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}}=(x-t, x+t) \cap \frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}} \cap [0, 1]$. The arbitrariness of $t$ shows that $x$ is adherent to the intersection $\frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}} \cap [0, 1]$.  We therefore have $(0, 1) \subseteq \overline{\frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}} \cap [0, 1]}$ and since $\{0, 1\} \subseteq \frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}} \cap [0, 1]$ the converse inclusion $[0, 1] \subseteq \overline{\frac{\mathbb{N}}{2^{\mathbb{N}}} \cap [0, 1]}$ is also established.
5. We appeal to relation $(^{**})$ in order to prove by means of induction on $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that for any set $I$ such that $|I|=2^n$ and for any family $x \in \mathbb{R}^I$ the generalised relation:
   $$f\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i \in I}x_i \right)=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i \in I}f(x_i)  \label{diad} \tag{diad}$$
   also holds. Indeed, the base case $n=0$ holds trivially. Assuming relation $\eqref{diad}$ for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let us consider set $I$ such that $|I|=2^{n+1}$ and family $x \in \mathbb{R}^I$. By bijective transportation of partitions, there exist two subsets $J, K \subseteq I$ such that $J \cap K=\varnothing$, $J \cup K=I$ and $|J|=|K|=2^n$. Since relation $\eqref{diad}$ is valid for both of the restrictions $x_{|J}$ and $x_{|K}$ we derive:
   $$\begin{align*}
   f\left(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{i \in I}x_i\right)&=f\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i \in J}x_i+\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i \in K}x_i\right)\right)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\left(f\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i \in J}x_i\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i \in K}x_i\right)\right)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i \in J}f(x_i)+\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i \in K}f(x_i)\right)\\
   &=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{i \in I}f(x_i).
   \end{align*}$$
   Having established this relation (family of relations), let us now argue that $2^{\mathbb{N}} \subseteq T$. Consider arbitrary $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and define the family $u:=\{(1, 2^nx+(1-2^n)y)\} \cup \left(y\right)_{2 \leqslant k \leqslant 2^n}$, in other words the family $u \in \mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ given by:
   $$u_k=\begin{cases}
   2^nx+(1-2^n)y, &k=1\\
   y, &2 \leqslant k \leqslant 2^n.
   \end{cases}$$
   Applying the relation $\eqref{diad}$ to $u$ we obtain:
   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}(f(2^nx+(1-2^n)y)+(2^n-1)f(y)),$$
   which is easily rearranged to give the desired:
   $$f(2^nx+(1-2^n)y)=2^nf(x)+(1-2^n)f(y).$$
6. At this point we shall prove that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq T$. In order to achieve this it will suffice to show that $\mathbb{N} \subseteq T$ for then we shall also have $1-\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{Z}_{-} \cup \{1\} \subseteq 1-T=T$. Consider now an arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since any natural number has a unique diadic expansion, there exists a *finite* subset $M \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $n=\displaystyle\sum_{k \in M}2^k$. Setting $r\colon=|M|$, there exists $s \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^s \geqslant r$. Since $M$ is finite it is clearly bounded in $\mathbb{N}$ and there exists therefore $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k\leqslant m$ for all $k \in M$. By an inductive argument entirely similar to the one conducted above at 5), one can prove that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, any set $I$ such that $|I|=2^n$ and any family $t \in T^I$ one has $\frac{1}{2^n}\displaystyle\sum_{i \in I}t_i \in T$. Consider now the set $N\colon=M \cup ([m+1, m+2^s-r] \cap \mathbb{N})$  and the family $t \in T^N$ given by:
   $$t_k=\begin{cases}
   2^{s+k}, &k \in M\\
   0, &m+1 \leqslant k \leqslant m+2^s-r.
   \end{cases}$$
   Since by construction $M \cap [m+1, m+2^s-r]=\varnothing$, we easily gather that $|N|=|M|+2^s-r=2^s$ so that by virtue of the observation above we infer that:
   $$\frac{1}{2^s}\sum_{k \in N}t_k=\frac{1}{2^s}\sum_{k \in M}2^{s+k}=\sum_{k \in M}2^k=n \in T.$$
7. We have reached the final stage, where we shall prove that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq T$. For arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$ denote by $[x]$ respectively $\{x\}$ the *integer part* respectively *fractionary part* of $x$, in other words the numbers given by:
   $$\begin{align*}
   [x]\colon&=\min(\mathbb{Z} \cap (-\infty, x])\\
   \{x\}\colon&=x-[x].
   \end{align*}$$
   Consider an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In the case $\{x\} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ we have that $2\{x\} \in [0, 1] \subseteq T$ by virtue of 4) and $2[x] \in \mathbb{Z} \subseteq T$ by virtue of 6), whence from 1) we gather that:
   $$\frac{2[x]+2\{x\}}{2}=x \in T.$$
   This reasoning allows us to conclude that $\mathbb{Z}+\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right] \subseteq T$. It follows that $1-\left(\mathbb{Z}+\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right]\right)=\mathbb{Z}+\left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right] \subseteq 1-T=T$. We conclude by exhibiting the relations:
   $$\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{R}&=\mathbb{Z}+[0, 1) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}+[0, 1]\\
   &=\mathbb{Z}+\left(\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right] \cup \left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right]\right)\\
   &=\left(\mathbb{Z}+\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right]\right) \cup \left(\mathbb{Z}+\left[\frac{1}{2}, 1\right]\right)\\
   &\subseteq T.
   \end{align*}$$

---

**Shorter proof of the claim** $T=\mathbb{R}$

Starting from the inclusion $[0, 1] \subseteq T$ already proved at 5) above, one can argue in a more direct manner that $\mathbb{R} \subseteq T$. This argument takes its most general form as follows:

> Let $(\mathbf{K}, +, \cdot, \mathbf{R})$ be a totally ordered (not necessarily commutative) field ($\mathbf{R}$ is the total order), $\mathbf{V}$, $\mathbf{V’}$ two left $\mathbf{K}$-vector spaces and $\mathscr{A}$, $\mathscr{B}$ two affine spaces such that their translation spaces (also called director spaces) are $\mathrm{Dir}\mathscr{A}=\mathbf{V}$ respectively $\mathrm{Dir}\mathscr{B}=\mathbf{V’}$. Let $\varphi \colon \mathscr{A } \to \mathscr{B}$ be a map such that $\varphi(\lambda X+(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\lambda)Y)=\lambda \varphi(X)+(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\lambda)\varphi(Y)$ for any points $X, Y \in \mathscr{A}$ and any scalar $\lambda \in [0_{\mathbf{K}}, 1_{\mathbf{K}}]_{\mathbf{R}}$. Then the map $\varphi$ is affine.

*Proof.* In order to show $\varphi$ is affine we introduce the set:
$$\Theta\colon=\{\theta \in K|\ (\forall X, Y)(X, Y \in \mathscr{A} \Rightarrow \varphi(\theta X+(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)Y)=\theta \varphi(X)+(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)\varphi(Y))\}$$
and seek to prove that $\Theta=\mathbf{K}$. By hypothesis we are given that $[0_{\mathbf{K}}, 1_{\mathbf{K}}]_{\mathbf{R}} \subseteq \Theta$.

Consider now arbitrary points $X, Y \in \mathscr{A}$ and scalar $\theta \in \mathbf{K} \setminus [0_{\mathbf{K}}, 1_{\mathbf{K}}]_{\mathbf{R}}=(\leftarrow, 0_{\mathbf{K}})_{\mathbf{R}} \cup (1_{\mathbf{K}}, \rightarrow)_{\mathbf{R}}$. Set $Z\colon=\theta X+(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)Y$.

If $\theta<_{\mathbf{R}}0_{\mathbf{K}}$, we gather that $1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta>_{\mathbf{R}}1_{\mathbf{K}}$ and thus $(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)^{-1} \in (0_{\mathbf{K}}, 1_{\mathbf{K}})_{\mathbf{R}} \subseteq \Theta$. Since $Y=(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)^{-1}Z-\theta(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)^{-1}X$, we have that $\varphi(Y)=(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)^{-1}\varphi(Z)-\theta(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)^{-1}\varphi(X)$, which after rearrangement leads to:
$\varphi(Z)=\theta \varphi(X)+(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)\varphi(Y)$. As a remark, these affine combination expansions are justified by the fact that – although the field $\mathbf{K}$ is not assumed to be commutative – nevertheless the elements $\lambda$ and $(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\lambda)^{-1}$ *commute* for any $\lambda \in \mathbf{K} \setminus \{1_{\mathbf{K}}\}$.

If on the other hand $\theta>_{\mathbf{R}}1_{\mathbf{K}}$ we have $\theta^{-1} \in (0_{\mathbf{K}}, 1_{\mathbf{K}})_{\mathbf{R}} \subseteq \Theta$ and since $X=\theta^{-1}Z+\left(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta^{-1}\right)Y$ we have the relation $\varphi(X)=\theta^{-1}\varphi(Z)+\left(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta^{-1}\right)\varphi(Y)$, which after rearrangement becomes $\varphi(Z)=\theta\varphi(X)+(1_{\mathbf{K}}-\theta)\varphi(Y)$.

This shows that $\mathbf{K} \subseteq \Theta$ and entails the fact that $\varphi$ is indeed affine. $\Box$

Answer (score 1):

A simpler consideration:
If
$$\frac{1}{2y} \int_{x-y}^{x+y} f(t) dt=f(x).~~~~(1)$$
Then  $$f(0)=\frac{1}{2y} \int_{-y}^{y} f(t) dt. ~~~~(2)$$
Also, for the RHS to be independent of $y$, the only choice is the linear function $f(t)=at+b.$
Then (1) gives the identical linear function: $f(x)=ax+b$.
Next, (2) shows consistency by giving $f(0)=b$ (independent of $y$).

Hence, the solution of (1) is a linear function only.

Comment: "Also, for the RHS to be independent of $y$, the only choice is the linear function  $f(t)=at+b$." This seems like a nontrivial step to me, and requires something like the argument in Robert Z's answer, I believe. That would then still require that $f$ is twice differentiable.

Comment: Yes, you may say two solutions are possible $f(t)=at+b, f(t)=b$.

Comment: @Lukas Miristwhisky You are right indeed about that claim concealing a highly nontrivial argumentation, however the hypothesis that $f$ is twice differentiable is unnecessarily strong. Relation (1) and continuity suffice in order to prove that $f$ is affine.